# Why selecte option change event can't have this and event.target to get selected value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In select option change event, why can't we get `this` or `event.target` to get selected value instead of writing clumsy code like `$( "select option:selected" )` to get selected value?

Because I came across problem where I have to access some `data-*` attributes in option on dom when change event get fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From [*docs*](http://api.jquery.com/on/), *When `jQuery` calls a handler, the this keyword is a reference to the element where the **event is being delivered**; for directly bound events this is the element where the event was attached and for delegated events this is an element matching selector. (Note that this may not be equal to event.target if the event has bubbled from a descendant element.)*

For `select-change` event, this `refers` to `select` element hence you can get the value using `this.value` or `$(this).val()`.

To get the `data-*` attributes of `option` elements,

Use `$('option:selected', this)` as this will select only those options which are under the context of `changed` select-element(`this`)